# How do neighborhoods work in London?

Tags: uk, london

How do white and Asian British people generally live in London?

Do they **predominantly** live away from each other in segregated neighborhoods, or do they live in the same neighborhood?

Do Asian Muslims live **mostly** in white-free areas or do they live with whites?

I mean, is there any pattern there?

Comment: Can you provide a context? Why do you need this information for travel? Are you looking for, say authentic restaurants and shops?

Comment: @AnishSheela, I will rent a place to stay.

Comment: Its better to ask in Expatriates stackexchange.

Comment: @AnishSheela, *Its better to ask in Expatriates stackexchange.* --- this has nothing to do with EXPAT.SE.

Comment: Are you just visiting London for a few days and want a location that would be convenient for an Asian Muslim to stay? Mosque, halal food, etc?

Comment: @travelgasm, Yes. I want to rent a property for my family and me for four months. But, also I am interested in knowing how people generally live in London.

Comment: Please note: London is in England, not pre-1994 South Africa.

Answer (score 9):

According to http://www.muslimsinbritain.org/guide/guide3.html#3.3 the main countries of origin among Muslims in London are Bangladesh, Pakistan and India, followed by Turkey/Cyprus, Algeria, Morocco, sub-Saharan West Africa, the Sahel or Horn of Africa, Egypt, Indonesia /Malaysia/ Singapore. At least 96% of Muslims in Britain, and approximately 1520 or 96% of masjids or mosques, are Sunni, and about 2% are Shi’a, with 67 masjids.

The physical size of Greater London, England, is 607 square miles. There is a Muslim community in all of its 32 boroughs and in the City of London. Eleven of the boroughs have a Muslim population of 10% or more. The largest concentration of Muslim residents is in Tower Hamlets (71,389 representing 36.4% of the population), followed by Newham (59,293; 24.3%). At the other end of the scale are Bexley (3,069; 1.4%) and Havering (1,800; 0.8%).

There is no ‘segregation’ nor are there ‘white-free areas’.

Note: data is from the 2011 Census.